# How can you erase a particular value in the list?

Tags: python

**How can you erase a particular value in the list?**

The value of the list exists.

```
review_list = ["14hour","16hour","20hour","24hour","8hour","4hour","2hour","hello","jae12"]
```

If you look at the list value,

Only numeric values change before int(1-24)hour.

How can you remove int (1-24)hour and output the remaining values?

OUTPUT

```
review_list = "hello","jae12"]
```

Comment: Why have you tagged selenium in this case?

Comment: Is it possible to have 'somehour' or '123hour' in your `review_list`? If yes, should they be removed or not?

Comment: @Shubham Periwal sorry, this post tag remove selenium.

Comment: @JeffC I tried so many times to get the result value, but I didn't upload . because it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected output, you want to remove elements which contain "hour" in the value

```
review_list = ["14hour","16hour","20hour","24hour","8hour","4hour","2hour","hello","jae12"]
review_filtered = [x for x in review_list if "hour" not in x]
```

Output

```
["hello", "jae12"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
review_list = list(filter(lambda item: not item.endswith("hour"), review_list))
```

or

```
import re
review_list = list(filter(lambda item: not re.match('^[0-9]+hour$',item), review_list))
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to overwrite the inputs... change your final variable name to `filtered_list` or something other than `review_list`

Comment: @JeffC to avoid filtering words that end with `hour` but not starts with [0-9]...